# get_results $wpdb order by name asc

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to sort data ordered alphabetically.

```
 $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT name, term_id FROM wp_catidx WHERE alpha = %s", $pageletter));
```

I tried dozens of ways and i did not succeed, can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can sort data by adding "ORDER BY name ASC"

```
 $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT name, term_id FROM wp_catidx WHERE alpha = %s ORDER BY name ASC", $pageletter));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT name, term_id
    FROM wp_catidx
    WHERE alpha = %s
    ORDER BY name",
$pageletter));
```